# How to add a timestamp or r.now field in a horizon.io application

Tags: rethinkdb, horizon

I am trying to add a created_at and updated_at field in my data and exploring ways to accomplish this.

What is the easiest way to add a timestamp to the data WITHOUT creating it myself? I would like this to be solved on the rethinkdb layer if possible.